# How can I count "\n\n" in a string with Python?

Tags: python

This is my string: (information: I parsed it with Python from an array to string with str(myString)):

```py
myString = "[('das ist ein Test', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam\norem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\norem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\norem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\norem ipsum dolor sit amet')]"
```

When I try:

`print(myString.count("\n\n"))`

I get the answer: 0

But it should be 3.

Comment: i got 3 on my system

Comment: Are you sure that's a `str`ing or `list` of `tuple` ?

Comment: @hansolo, look at the double quotes.

Comment: ok if i take the string and count it in the python console it works, but i have a list and i parse it with str(list). is this not possible ?

Comment: @FlorianBuchfink No, that won't work because `str(list)` would have escaped the `\n` and that would have became `\\n\\n`. Try `str(thatlist).count('\\n\\n')`

Comment: @hansolo thank you!  if I count \\n\\n it works!

Comment: You can use `''.join(input_list)` instead of `str(input_list)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert a list to a string with `str([…])`, Python creates string representations for all elements of the list using `repr()`.

This causes all special characters in strings in the list to be escaped, e.g. `\n` (newline) becomes a literal `\n` (backslash + 'n').

So for this case, you need to check for `\\n\\n` or use a raw string:

```
print(myString.count("\\n\\n"))

print(myString.count(r"\n\n"))
```

Alternatively, go through every element of the tuples in the list and sum the results:

```
sum([stringItem.count('\n\n') for myTuple in myArray for stringItem in myTuple])
```